# How do I separate the following three lists into 7 groups?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to separate those elements in A and B and C. I have tried to use if else but it seems a bit hard-coded.

```
A = ["a","b","c","d"]
B = ["a","c","g","e"]
C = ["a","b","f","e"]
X = [[]*7]
common = set(A+B+C)
common1 = set(A) & set(B) & set(C)
common2 = set(A) & set(B)
common3 = set(A) & set(C)
common4 = set(C) & set(B)
for e in common:
    if e in common1:
        X[0] += e
    elif e in common2:
        X[1] += e
    elif e in common3:
        X[2] += e
    elif e in common4:
        X[3] += e
    elif e in A:
        X[4] += e
    elif e in B:
        X[5] += e
    else:
        X[6] += e



X[0] should contain elements common in A,B,C
X[1] should contain elements common in A,B.
X[2] should contain elements common in A,C.
X[3] should contain elements common in C,B.
X[4] should contain elements common in A.
X[5] should contain elements common in B.
X[6] should contain elements common in C.
```

Is it better be done in dictionary?

Comment: Have a look here : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: @hiro protagonist you are right!   X = [set(A)&set(B)&set(C), set(A)&set(B), set(A)&set(C), set(C)&set(B), set(A), set(B), set(C)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not very nice code but does what you want:

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce

A = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
B = ["a", "c", "g", "e"]
C = ["a", "b", "f", "e"]

lst = (set(A), set(B), set(C))
ret = []
for r in range(3, 0, -1):
    for comb in combinations(lst, r=r):
        ret.append(reduce(and_, comb))
print(ret)
```

i converted your lists to sets; `set_a & set_b` (`add_(set_a, set_b)`, respectively) selects the items that are in both sets. `itertools.combinations` called with `r=3`, `r=2` and `r=1` selects the combinations in the order you need.

Comment: Nice use of `combinations`

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks. on the other hand: weird way (or data structure) to arrange the result...

Answer (score 1):

I would use sets and `set.intersection` for this:

```
A = set(["a","b","c","d"])
B = set(["a","c","g","e"])
C = set(["a","b","f","e"])
X = [
    list(A.intersection(B,C)),
    list(A.intersection(B)),
    list(A.intersection(C)),
    list(B.intersection(C)),
    list(A),
    list(B),
    list(C)]
```

Not as extensible as @hiro's code but it's easy to see what it's doing at a glance.